# Where can i find a how-to for writing a wagon for maven 3?

Tags: api, maven-3, sourceforge, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

Maven has changed from version 2 to 3 and so it has changed the ioc container from plexus to google guice.

So my wagon (to download artifacts from sourceforge file release area) for maven 2 must be rewritten to maven 3 to satisfy guice.
Is there a tutorial / api description / to learn how to change from plexus wagon to guice wagon?

Comment: At the moment the current implementation of my wagon could not be build under maven 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector is a good example to use wagon in maven 3

Comment: Thanks, i have found the related sources under:
https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-aether.git